# A potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client in server

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I got an error from my web application which is got from my live site " a potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client in server". I am enable the `ValidateRequest="false"` in to the corresponding page and added the `requestValidationMode="2.0"` in the webconfig file and I am using the Html. Encode and decode concept but still I got this error in my live site but this application works well in my localhost. Let me know what I did wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In framework 4.0 you have to set requestValidationMode value to 2.0 in web config to make this work

```
<system.web>
     <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
     <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: you mean the problem is after depolying the application i did not set the debug="false" right?

Comment: No what I meant was adding the following entry in your web config,if your are using asp.net 4.0

Comment: because i already added the requestValidationMode="2.0" in my web config